# Send more then one PDF file using Google Apps Script

Tags: email, pdf, google-apps-script

I used that method to send some files through mail, but I'm having issues to send PDF files, they are not enconding back.

```
function sendEmail() {

  var files = [
    "1X0YYxxtnKJtkn9BhoBcSb265acOYOnWJytQeBKEvfqU",  
    "12r6Owm616Ioqj9EfOgkNqPgXNi88f_chdPRyBcSC2EM"  
  ]; 

  var attachments = [];

  for (var f in files) {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(files[f]);
    attachments.push({
      "type": file.getMimeType(),
      "name": file.getName(), 
      "content": Utilities.base64Encode(file.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').getBytes()) 
   }); 
 }

  MailApp.sendEmail('mail@gmail.com', 'Attachment example', 'Two files are attached.', {
     name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
     attachments: attachments
 }); 

}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I not sure that you can put "type" and "name" or even "content" inside an object and then put that in the array.  The documentation only shows the file in the attachments array, nothing else.  You *can* enter multiple files into the attachments array, but that's all I think.  So, I'd try that, and try putting the blob source into it's own variable name, at least for debugging.  Get something simple to work, and then build from there if you need to.